# Internacionalização na arquitetura DDD (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: c#, ddd, internacionalização

Qual seria a melhor estratégia para internacionalizar um sistema na arquitetura DDD, sabendo-se que temos strings para internacionalizar presentes nas camadas:

1. Presentation - Views
2. Application - ViewModels nos DataAnnotation
3. Domain - Validation e Specifications

Levando em consideração que a camada Domain não deve conhecer nenhuma camada, seria descartado a possibilidade de criar um projeto de internacionalização em uma camada que permeie todas as outras?

Comment: "seria descartado a possibilidade de criar um projeto de internacionalização em uma camada que permeie todas as outras?" Na minha opinião, não seria descartado, esse projeto de internacionalização é claramente um cross cutting concern.

Comment: Ola Marcell! Mas o que você me diz pela camada Domain ser agnóstica, ou seja, ela não depender de nenhuma outra, mesmo assim você acha interessante criar um projeto CrossCutting, pois ai o meu domínio conheceria esse projeto.

Comment: Deixo como dica esse framework, e como ele lidou com localização:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization

Usando IOC você consegue criar uma camada de crosscutting sem relação direta com o domain.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que a melhor forma é usar nas DLLs de Domain o Resource, uma para cada idioma que você deseja, depois só tratar as chamadas para usar a cultura certa, se for Asp.NEt core, tem um exemplo no link abiaxo, ach oque é um exemplo bem completo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization

Comment: Obrigado TioRAC, consegui resolver, porém havia esquecido de comentar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigos, após investir um tempo em pesquisas resolvi meu problema de internacionalização criando uma camada CrossCutting, onde através das camadas eu realizo a internacionalização de todo o meu projeto, ou seja, consigo realizar a internacionalização das minhas Views (Camada presentation), ViewModel(Camada de aplicação),mensagens de validações, specificações,etc. (Camada de Domínio).

Aproveitando, criei uma ferramenta que automatiza todo o processo de criação das camadas (com exceção das minhas Views), baseando-se em consultas no banco, ou seja, para realizar um Crud simples em DDD, tenho uns 18 arquivos onde são gerados em apenas um clique.
Irei futuramente disponibiliza-lo para ajudar a comunidade de desenvolvedores